# How to change color of a Like button on react native with galio

Tags: android, react-native

I want to implement a like button that changes it's icon color when it's liked and that can be disliked reverting the color change and like stored in my app. I am using react Native with expo and the galio frameworks This is my attempt:

```
function like_quote(_this) {
    _this.setState( {iconColor: theme.COLORS.THEME })
    //_this.iconColor= theme.COLORS.THEME //I also tried this
    Alert.alert('Like!') //this is supposed to be where I store the like for my app
}
```

this inside the render()

```
...
            <Button
              onlyIcon
              icon="heart"
          key="like"
              iconFamily="font-awesome"
              iconSize={theme.SIZES.BASE}
              iconColor={'#ffbbbb'}//theme.COLORS.THEME
              color="transparent"
              style={{ marginRight: theme.SIZES.BASE }}
              onPress={() => like_quote(this)}
            />,
    ...
```

Though it does nothing to the button. The Alert works fine but the icon color doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the color of the icon according to your state either it's liked or unliked.

```
    like_quote = () => {
    this.setState({iconColor: theme.COLORS.THEME })
    Alert.alert('Like!') //this is supposed to be where I store the 
    like for my app
    }

      <Button
          onlyIcon
          icon="heart"
          key="like"
          iconFamily="font-awesome"
          iconSize={theme.SIZES.BASE}
          iconColor={this.state.iconColor}  //theme.COLORS.THEME
          color="transparent"
          style={{ marginRight: theme.SIZES.BASE }}
          onPress={() => like_quote()}
        />
```

Here is I have created a snack where you can see an example, On every button press color, is been change of icon

https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/smiling-carrot

Comment: I get: TypeError: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.iconColor'

Comment: Here I have set an example for you.
https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/smiling-carrot

Comment: Above error, you are getting because you haven't set an initial state for iconColor.

Comment: Thanks I corrected it! But now I get the error _this.setState is not a function. (In '_this.setState({ iconColor: _theme.default.COLORS.THEME})','_this.setState' is undefined) when I put the function outside the export and it can't find the like_quote variable when it's inside the export like in your snack.

Comment: Can you please make a snack with the issue and code ?if yes then please share it with me, i will fix it.

Comment: I don't know how to make the snack run but here it is: https://snack.expo.io/dgH2ibpcY

Comment: I got the solution from reddit it's using: onPress ={()=>{this.like_quote()}}